# ionic cordova build --release android not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[image]

need to release apk trying to

```
ionic cordova build --release android
```

was working fine.. after anroid studio update 3.0 error occurred

```
error cannot read property length of undefined
```

I have already installed sdk ,android studio. I already checked path of sdk and android.

> Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "D:\raj\myspot_app_0
>   80218_frmRaj\brahamin mobile
>   application\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_cl
>   ass.js" "D:\raj\myspot_app_080218_frmRaj\brahamin mobile application"
>           add to body class: platform-android
>           ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Vidya\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>           JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
>           Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: what is your cordova-android version?

Comment: Read this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-when-build-or-run/92149/3

This may solve your issue

Comment: Cordova version: 8.0.0